# C# Binary search

Tags: c#, binary-search

so I am trying to learn and practice binary search but unfortunately can not understand how binary search could work for a List of objects or just strings for example. It does not look that complicated when you deal with numbers. But how do u actually perform a binary search for instance with list of object which holds property name inside as a string value.

Comment: Why should this be more complicated?

Answer (score 1):

Binary search assumes sorted collection. So, you have to provide a `compare(a,b)` function. That function will return -1,0 or 1 as the result of the comparison. The function implementation for numbers or chars is trivial. But, you can implement a much more complex logic that takes one or more object properties into consideration. As long as you provide that function, you can sort any collection of the objects and you can apply binary search on that collection.

Answer (score 0):

You would do it the same way as with numbers, the only difference is, that you access the property of the instance you are looking at.

For example `items[x].Value` instead of `items[x]`.

Comment: I guess OP is talking about how to compare strings??

Answer (score 0):

Say you have a list of friends which use the Friend Class and you want to use a binary search to find if a friends exists in this list. Firstly, a binary search should only be conducted on a sorted list. Using lambda, you can order the list and then change it to an array. In this example I am collecting the input into from a textbox (which is looking for the name of the friend) after a button is clicked and then conducting the binary search. The Friend class must also implement IComparable.

```
class Friend : IComparable<Friend>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Likes { get; set; }
    public string Dislikes { get; set; }
    public int Birthday { get; set; }

    //Used for the binary search
    public int CompareTo(Friend other)
    {
        return this.Name.CompareTo(other.Name);
    }
}

class MainWindow
{
    List<Friend> friends = new List<Friend>();

    //other functions here populated the list

    private void OnButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Friend[] sortedArray = friends.OrderBy(f => f.Name).ToArray();

        int index = Array.BinarySearch(sortedArray, new Friend() { Name = tb_binarySearch.Text });

        if (index < 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Friend does not exist in list");
        } 
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Your friend exists at index {0}", index);
        }

    }
}
```

If the index returns as a negative number, the object does not exist. Otherwise it will be the index of the object in the sorted list.